# USA visa- Does passport withdrawal during 221g processing cause application withdrawal too?

Tags: usa

My current F1 visa was supposed to expire in mid-2018 and since I wasn't sure if I would visit my home country next year, I applied for renewal of F1 visa for United States in my recent trip to home country and I got 221g status. Since my current F1 was still valid and I had some urgent travel plans to visit USA, I decided to withdraw my passport temporarily hoping to use my existing F1 visa. But I received my passport back with 'CANCELED WITHOUT PREJUDICE' imprinted on my F1 visa. Is my F1 visa application also withdrawn or is it still under processing? Or do I have to reapply for F1 visa? And also, why was my previous F1 visa canceled?

Comment: Is 'Cancelled without prejudice' on a new copy of the visa stamp or was that printed on the existing visa that you had used to travel before?

Comment: On the existing visa used to travel before.

Comment: I do not know whether your application was withdrawn when your passport was withdrawn, but I suspect that your application will continue to be considered.  The cancellation of your previous visa seems to be standard procedure.  It is [mandated for certain other visa types](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040212.html) that an existing visa be cancelled when the application for a replacement is made, not after the decision to grant the replacement is made.